# What is this Dimension-brand 135mm lens?

Tags: lens, old-lenses, equipment-identification

Kind of what it says on the tin. I got this lens, sans caps, as a gift from a friend (who doesn't really know photography). It's dusty but otherwise seems to be in decent condition, but I can't seem to find any information about it on the Interwebz.

It's got a "clicky" (non-continuous) aperture adjustment, and an auto/manual aperture switch located at the base. Minimum focus is 1.5m.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Sorry about the awful quality — these were taken with my phone (I know, I know).

**EDIT**: I've found [a description](http://m42lens.com/m42-lens-database/791-prinzflex-auto-reflex-135mm-f-3-5-22) for a lens that's an exact match for this one, but with Prinzflex branding. I wonder what company did the original design work?

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be a [M42 mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M42_lens_mount) lens. The "Dimension" brand was probably a store-label brand made by Sun, Cosina, Chinon, or some such other lensmaker. ("Dimension" is unfortunately a *horrible* name to Google for...)

This thread at [MFLenses Forums](http://forum.mflenses.com/need-help-identifying-lens-dimension-135mm-f3-5-t53724.html) apparently covers the exact same lens model (it's old enough that a lot of the image links are broken). Apparently it's a very decent lens.

---

**Note:** Michael Clark helpfully suggested to mention the similarity between the M42 mount and the T-mount. Both mounts are 42mm threads.

- The M42 mount has a 1mm thread pitch; thus, it's more fully specified as M42×1.
- The T-mount has a 0.75mm thread pitch; thus, it's more fully specified as M42×0.75.

If the thread pitch doesn't stand out as an obvious distinction (it can be hard to tell the difference), another *possible* giveaway is the aperture pin: although Sigma's YS mount (which was based on the T-mount) had an aperture pin, many more M42-mount lenses had aperture pins than YS-mount lenses did. Of course, not *all* M42-mount lenses had aperture pins, so you're back to measuring thread pitch.

Takeaway: **make sure to measure the thread pitch before assuming M42**.

See also: the [accepted answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/19568/11924) to [How do I identify unknown thread mounts?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/19566/11924)

Comment: It might also be a T-mount lens, which has a 42mm x 0.75mm thread pitch rather than the M42 42mm x 1.0mm thread pitch. Although fewer T-mount lenses had aperture pins, Sigma's YS mount based on the T-mount did.

Comment: @MichaelClark indeed, I didn't consider T-mount. To my eye, the thread pitch appears fairly wide, and from a numbers standpoint, there were probably far more M42 lenses made.

Comment: I agree the lens pictured is almost certainly an M42 mount. But someone else with a T-mount lens who finds this question might not notice the difference. That could lead to buying the wrong adapter for use with a modern camera.

Comment: It is, in fact, an M42 mount - I tested it with an old Praktica my dad had lying around.

Comment: Could be Chinon from the looks of it..